# DDR memory errors or page cache corruption?

Tags: linux, embedded, cache, arm64

System: embedded, arm64 (4xCortexA53), 2GB LPDDR3, eMMC memory, Linux, kernel 5.4.17.

I am experiencing issues with random system crash, that in normal operation will happen every 2 days to every "several weeks", depending on device or setup. We narrowed this to following testing scenario that may trigger the root cause:

1. Read files from filesystem (rootfs, read-only partition): /usr/bin/, /etc/, /usr/lib and so on
2. Calculate md5sum from file and write that to tmp/log file
3. Repeat loop - if md5sum differs on the next run - save "modified" file.

It appears that after many loops files start to differ and it may happen to a random file: binary, or lib or scripts. The difference is not totally random: only every second byte is wrong. It may be odd or even bytes, but never total random mess. We could not trace any pattern in the bad bytes (i.e. single bit flip, other file mixed in etc.). Size of the malformed block is also random (more than one page anyway).

[image: hexdfiff view between good and bad file]

To bring back file to "normal state" it is enough to clear page cache or inode cache with echo to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches. Thus it is rather not issue with eMMC memory. Periodic clearing of cache will not help either - each run is somehow separate and may cause issue anyway.

I am suspecting low level issues with DDR setup/layout, issue with page cache (less likely) or a heavy memory leak.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to get physical address of the allocated, malformed page using some linux tools? I guess it is possible to get mmped memory block of the file, find virtual page, translate virtual addres to pysical address - any single tool to help with that?
2. Could DDR refresh timing play a role here?
3. I have read about "raw hammer" issue in DDRs but this seems to be so specific that also not really probable. Anyone has some experience?

I would appreciate any hint. THanks

Comment: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm is available for ARM64, please run it for a few hours at least.

Comment: I have seen this tool, but my system is headless and has no uefi/bios boot. I'd need to somehow extract boot img and boot it straight into console mode (making sure its console is attached to proper serial port etc.). This is currently beyond my skills, if possible at all.

Comment: `sudo apt install memtester`, kill most of the running applications/services (to free up as much RAM as possible) except SSHD obviously, run it. And then there's a builtin `memtest` feature in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Unfortunatelly memory tests do not show any problem. I run "memtester" for several days, using different settings: for small chunks or big chunks of memory (1M with 10k loops or 500M with 1 loop) etc. Not a single crash for days. I could not use memtest86 - it is targeted for PCs, my devices is headless, based on non-UEFI bootloader/arm64 and it would be very difficult to boot it from this tool if possible at all. I have tested 4 different LPDDR vendors and only one has issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling DDR self-refresh helps. Seems to be CPU and/or DDR vendor related, rather than general DDR problem. Needs to be done in bootloader at DDR setup stage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).